# Android device 3.2+ picks from layout-large

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have the following folders for layouts : 
layout,
layout-large,
layout-xlarge,
layout-sw720dp

As far as I know, For Android 3.2+, if you have at least one folder that uses the new size quantifiers then it assumes that you are using these new size quantifiers everywhere and ignores any other folder that uses the old quantifiers.

Since I have one folder (i.e. layout-sw720dp) with the new quantifier, I would expect Nexus 7 to pick layouts from the default layout folder. But it is picking the layout from layout-large folder. Can someone please help me understand why?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: No. Thanks for the answer. But I am currently busy with something else and so am not able to try it out. Will get back to this very soon and shall check your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found the solution to my question:
 For Android 3.2+, if you have at least one folder that uses the new size quantifiers then it assumes that you are using these new size quantifiers everywhere and ignores any other folder that uses the old quantifiers.

But the way Android finds out whether you have a folder with new size quantifier is slightly different.
 It checks for new size quantifier folders only equal to and below the sw of the device that it's running on.

For example, for Nexus 7 Android would look for folders in the order sw600dp, sw480dp, sw360dp, sw320dp and finally if none of those are present it picks from layout folder. sw720dp though present  is not taken into consideration since it is out of range for a nexus 7 device.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the same files you have in layout-large to `layout-sw480dp` or reference the layout from within there.

Anyway: As most devices below 3.0 are phones which are most likely not `large` nor `xlarge` and there are nearly no devices out there running android 3.0 or 3.1, I strongly recommend to drop `layout-large` and `layout-xlarge` completely and just stick to the new folders.

Comment: Hi there, just a random search, but want to use the trick, how can you make me sure, layout-sw480dp is workable, ???

Comment: let me share you, what I want... back to you soon.

Comment: Nexus 7 picks from layout-sw600dp and not layout-480dp.